# HTML5 video, -Mediaelement.js, Video.js, OR a non javascript solution?

Tags: video, html5-video, mediaelement.js, video.js

Confused by all the options for implementing html5 video. 
What are the arguments in favor of using a javascript based solution like
MediaElement
or
VideoJS
?

Another way of phrasing this question might be, under what conditions would a non-javascript html5 video solution be the better option (like that presented on http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody)?

Answer (score 3):

Reasons to use a JS based player:

- Consistent look and feel across browsers/platforms including Flash fallback
- Ability to work around device/browser bugs
- Extensibility.  Pretty common to hook other things into the playback/progress/state of a video.

Comment: Good answer. To expand on it, you get a consistent API between Flash and HTML5 if you want to make your own controls, or trigger other events on the page. With Video.js, it uses the same HTML/CSS skin for both HTML5 and Flash so you only have to make the skin once.